# SQL preventation of XSS

Tags: php, html, security, xss

Hey guys so Ive got a question, is there a something I could use when inserting data into the SQL to prevent XSS? Instead of when reading it.

For example I have quite bit of outputs from my sql that are user generated, is it possible to just make that safe on Entering SQL or do I have to make it safe when it leaves SQL?

TL:DR can I use something like htmlspecialchars when inserting data into SQL to prevent XSS, will that be any sort of good protection?

Comment: It is best to escape them when rendering them, not when storing them.  The best reason for this is that in the future, the format you want to output it in may not be HTML, and if its already escaped for HTML, you're going to have problems with it later.  So in short, yes, you have to make it safe after it leaves SQL.

Answer (score 2):

I think several things are mixed up in the question.

#### Preventing XSS with input validation

In general **you can't prevent XSS with input validation**, except very special cases when you can validate input for something verz strict like numbers only.

Consider this html page (let's imagine `<?=` is used to insert data into your html in your server-side language because you hinted at PHP, could of course differ by language used):

```
<script>
    var myVar = <?= var1 ?>;
</script>
```

In this case, `var1` on the server doesn't need to have *any* special character, only letters are enough to inject javascript. Whether that can be useful for an attacker depends on several things, but technically, this would be vulnerable to XSS with almost any input validation. Of course such assignment may not currently be in your Javascript, but how will you ensure that there never will be?

Another example is obviously DOM XSS, where input does not ever get to the server, but that's a different story.

Preventing XSS is an output encoding thing. Input validation may help in some cases, but will not provide sufficient protection in most cases.

#### Storing encoded values

It is generally **not a good idea to store values html-encoded in your database**. On the one hand, it makes searching, ordering, any kind of processing much more cumbersome. On the other hand, it violates single responsibility and separation of concerns. Encoding is a view-level thing, your backend database has nothing to do with how you will want to present that data. It's even more emphasized when you consider different encodings. HTML encoding is only ok if you want to write the data into an HTML context. If it's javascript (in a script tag, or in an on* attribute like onclick, or several other places), html encoding is not sufficient, let alone where you have more special outputs. Your database doesn't need to know, where the data will be used, it's an output thing, and as such, it should be handled by views.

Answer (score -1):

You should test the input for whitelist characters using a regex to only accept like [a-Z][0-9] for example. You'll have a big headache if you try the other way around, using a blacklist, because there are gigantic ways of exploiting input and catching them all is a big problem

Also, be aware of SqlInjections. You should use SqlMap on linux to test if your website is vulnerable

Comment: Well so far I can say my website is preety safe from any SQL injections, everything is escaped properly etc, but using for example htmlspecialchars while doing UPDATE or INSERT wouldnt do anything right? I mean for the XSS, it benefits only when outputing data?

Comment: It works when users try the obvious way of exploitation, which is just adding the characters. To be safe, you should test against other kinds of attacks, like hex characters or substring functions. Check the XSS Cheat Sheet for more info, https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Aha. The thing is, I just ran XSS ME plugin for firefox (I dont any protection at all on my website XSS wise) but Im getting results that there are no vurneabilities

EDIT: Results http://imgur.com/a/kvQ6n

Comment: to be REALLY REALLY sure, dont use plugins, use linux tools. XSSer for example

Comment: You should not use whitelist or blacklist to prevent XSS.  Properly escaping/encoding is the right approach 99.999% of the time.  I would say the only proper approach, but I'm sure their are rare exceptions.  Hint: This isn't one of them.